# Jenkins change the status of aborted pipeline

Tags: jenkins, devops

In the following pipeline I try to change the status of the whole pipeline to *UNSTABLE* in `post` section. However whenever a stage is aborted (stage 2 in this example), the status could not be changed anymore. Is this an expected behaviour or a bug in jenkins?

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('1') {
            steps {
                echo "Step 1"
            }
        }
        stage('2') {
            steps {
                input "Some message?"
            }
        }
        stage('3') {
            steps {
                echo "Step 3"
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        always {
            script {
                currentBuild.result = "UNSTABLE"
            }
            echo "${currentBuild.result}" // Prints Aborted when stage 2 is aborted.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @DashrathMundkar It is aborted. Although it should be UNSTABLE according to the post section.

Comment: How do you abort the stage? Are you setting currentBuild.result = "ABORTED"

Comment: @smelm No. Stage 2 contains an input step, which waits for the user approval. And when the user clicks on the Abort button in the UI the stage would be aborted.